# Logical error. Elements in std::string not replaced properly with for loop

Tags: c++

I'm currently doing a programming exercise from a C++ book for beginners. The task reads as follows: "Write a function that reverses the characters in a text string by using two pointers. The only function parameter shall be a pointer to the string."

My issue is that I haven't been able to make the characters swap properly, see the output below. (And I also made the assumption that the function parameter doesn't count, hence why I'm technically using three pointers).

I am almost certain that the problem has to do with the for loop. I wrote this pseudocode:

> 1. Assign value of element number i in at_front to the 1st element in transfer_back.
> 2. Assign value of element number elem in at_back to element number i in at_front.
> 3. Assign value of the 1st element in transfer_back to element number elem in at_back.
> 4. Increment i, decrement elem. Repeat loop until !(i < elem)

---

I wasn't sure whether of not I was supposed to take the null terminator into account. I tried writing (elem - 1) but that messed up with the characters even more so I've currently left it as it is.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void strrev(string *at_front) {
    string *transfer_back = at_front, *at_back = transfer_back;
    int elem = 0;

    while(at_back->operator[](elem) != '\0') {
        elem++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < elem; i++) {
        transfer_back->operator[](0) = at_front->operator[](i);
        at_front->operator[](i) = at_back->operator[](elem);
        at_back->operator[](elem) = transfer_back->operator[](0);
        elem--;
    }
}

int main() {

    string str = "ereh txet yna";
    string *point_str = &str;

    strrev(point_str);

    cout << *point_str << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
Expected output: "any text here"

Terminal window: "xany text her"
```

The fact that the 'x' has been assigned to the first element is something I haven't been able to grasp.

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Using [std::reverse](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) would be the obvious one-line solution.

Comment: You could save yourself a lot of work by simply using `std::swap` to exchange two items, the front item with the back item.  But what is your actual question?  I see a general "I can't get this to work" type question, but what are we to do next?  Give you the correct implementation?

Comment: "pointer" sounds to me like C string. Although, you can access the C string in a `std::string`, this doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct answer

```
void strrev(string *at_front) {
    string *at_back = at_front;
    char transfer_back;
    int elem = 0;

    while(at_back->operator[](elem) != '\0') {
        elem++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <elem; i++) {
        transfer_back = at_front->operator[](i);
        at_front->operator[](i) = at_back->operator[](elem);
        at_back->operator[](elem) = transfer_back;
        elem--;
    }
}
```

Let me explain why you have that error. `string *transfer_back = at_front` those two are pointed to the same reference, that is why when you change `transfer_back->operator[](0) = at_front->operator[](i);`this change will reflect in at_front string as well.

Answer (score 1):

> "Write a function that reverses the characters in a text string by using two pointers. The only function parameter shall be a pointer to the string."

This sounds to me like the question addresses C strings but not `std::string`.
Assuming my feeling is right, this could look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void strrev(char *at_front) {
    char *at_back = at_front;
    if (!*at_back) return; // early out in edge case
    // move at_back to end (last char before 0-terminator)
    while (at_back[1]) ++at_back;
    // reverse by swapping contents of front and back
    while (at_front < at_back) {
        std::swap(*at_front++, *at_back--);
    }
}

int main() {

    char str[] = "ereh txet yna";
    strrev(str);
    std::cout << str << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
any text here
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4630e85e65808a6f)</kbd>

**Note:**

I stored the original string in a `char str[]`.

If I had used `char *str = "ereh txet yna";` I had assigned an address of a constant string to `str`. This feels very wrong as I want to modify the contents of `str` which must not be done on constants.

`strrev()`:

The `at_back[1]` reads the next `char` after address in `at_back`. For a valid C string, this should be always possible as I excluded the empty string (consisting of 0-terminator only) before.

The swapping loop moves `at_front` as well as `at_back`. As the pointer is given as value, this has no "destructive" effect outside of `strrev()`.

Concerning `std::swap(*at_front++, *at_back--);`:

The swapping combines access to pointer contents with pointer increment/decrement, using postfix-increment/-decrement. IMHO, one of the rare cases where the postfix operators are useful somehow.

Alternatively, I could have written:

```
 std::swap(*at_front, *at_back); ++at_front; --at_back;
```

---

Please, note that [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) is a container class. A pointer to the container cannot be used to address its contained raw string directly. For this, `std::string` provides various access methods like e.g.

- `std::string::operator[]()`
- `std::string::at()`
- `std::string::data()`
- etc.